# edit_{$taxonomy} | Hook

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

Hi i am not very experienced with plugin development and i am using edit_{$taxonomy} | Hook but i am not able to get new updated values using this hook. Here is my code

```
function action_edit_taxonomy( $term_id, $t_id ){
$term = get_term($term_id);
print_r($term);
exit;
};
add_action( "edit_um_user_tag", 'action_edit_taxonomy', 10, 6 );
```

But $term is returning old term saved value, not which i am going to update now.
So how i will be able to get new value which i am going to update now.
I will really appreciate it if someone will guide me that where i am wrong with this code. I have tried to find out help but still the problem is there. I am already using get_term() function for create_{$taxonomy} | Hook and get_term is working for it but it is not returning correct value for edit_{$taxonomy} | Hook.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting old version of the term, because edit_{$taxonomy} action is fired after the term is updated but before term's cache is cleared. Use edited_{$taxonomy} hook, which fires your action after the term is updated and its cache is cleared.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time. It is working perfectly for me now and it saves lot of my time. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.